# Create few the same XML nodes from SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2014

I need to have different information in the same node path, but I want to have those paths separated, for a better problem understanding I have add my code. 
Below is a part of my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CREATE_XML] (@ID_NO NVARCHAR(10))
AS BEGIN
SELECT 
    1 AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers/TelephoneNumber/NumberTypeId",
    P.WORKTEL AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers/TelephoneNumber/Number",
    2 AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers/TelephoneNumber/NumberTypeId",
    P.MOBILE AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers/TelephoneNumber/Number",
    3 AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers/TelephoneNumber/NumberTypeId",
    P.HOMETEL AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers/TelephoneNumber/Number"      
FROM 
    DETAILS AS P WHERE ID_NO = @ID_NO 
FOR XML path('Telephones')
END
```

Actual output looks like:

```
<Telephones>
  <Case>
    <Client>
      <TelephoneNumbers>
        <TelephoneNumber>
          <NumberTypeId>1</NumberTypeId>
          <Number>11</Number>
          <NumberTypeId>2</NumberTypeId>
          <Number>33</Number>
          <NumberTypeId>3</NumberTypeId>
          <Number></Number>
        </TelephoneNumber>
      </TelephoneNumbers>
    </Client>
  </Case>
</Telephones>
```

But I need output like:

```
<Telephones>
  <Case>
    <Client>
      <TelephoneNumbers>
        <TelephoneNumber>
          <NumberTypeId>1</NumberTypeId>
          <Number>11</Number>
        </TelephoneNumber>
        <TelephoneNumber>
          <NumberTypeId>2</NumberTypeId>
          <Number>33</Number>
        </TelephoneNumber>
        <TelephoneNumber>
          <NumberTypeId>3</NumberTypeId>
          <Number></Number>
        </TelephoneNumber>
      </TelephoneNumbers>
    </Client>
  </Case>
</Telephones>
```

How can I achieve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I have found solution, I hope the answer will be helpful for somebody someday. Basically we need to create nested select statement as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CREATE_XML] (@ID_NO NVARCHAR(10))
AS BEGIN
SELECT   
    (SELECT 1 AS NumberTypeId,
        WORKTEL AS Number FROM DETAILS WHERE ID_NO = @ID_NO FOR XML PATH ('TelephoneNumber'), TYPE) AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers", 
    (SELECT 2 AS NumberTypeId,
        MOBILE AS Number FROM DETAILS WHERE ID_NO = @ID_NO FOR XML PATH('TelephoneNumber'), TYPE) AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers", 
    (SELECT 3 AS NumberTypeId,
        HOMETEL AS Number FROM DETAILS WHERE ID_NO = @ID_NO FOR XML PATH('TelephoneNumber'), TYPE) AS "Case/Client/TelephoneNumbers",      
FROM DETAILS AS P WHERE ID_NO = @ID_NO FOR XML path('Telephones')
END
```